# Heavy processing of asset "Outline Effect"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to show the outline of a 3D object using an [Outline Effect](https://github.com/JimmyCushnie/Outline-Effect-but-its-faster).
I actually installed the assets and included them in my project.

However, when the component "Outline Effect" was added to the camera, the FPS of the game was reduced by about 20%.
Also,as confirmed by the Profiler window, approximately 50% or more of the processing of the game was used by Outline's Renderer.
The number of objects is not very large.

I feel like I'm using it the right way, but I'm doing one exceptional thing, which is to make the Outline a prefab and generate it.
Is this the reason for heavy processing?

Also, "Outline Effect" must be a great asset, but if you know of any other way you can dynamically show / hide contours, please let me know.

Comment: Why is this tagged C? There is not a single line of C source code in your question. Could you please provide the correct tags?

Comment: --Outline Effect is written in C#. Is the tag invalid in this case? I thought C# reading was also needed to solve this problem.--

Ops, the tags were completely different. I'm sorry.

Comment: You did read that the one from your link is no longer maintained and you should use [this](https://github.com/cakeslice/Outline-Effect) instead?